# Specifying "subdirectory"-path for resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, ruby-on-rails-5

I want the following resourceful routes for `Team`:

```
/admin/users/teams
/admin/users/team/new
/admin/users/team/:id
etc...
```

With following route helpers

```
admin_teams_path
new_admin_teams_path
edit_admin_teams_path
etc...
```

But with the only namespacing I know and use

```
namespace :admin do
  namespace :users do
    resources :teams, except: [:index]
  end
end
```

I just get these long route helpers with "users" in them:

```
admin_users_teams_path
new_admin_users_teams_path
edit_admin_users_teams_path
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `users` namespace and use the `path` option in your route:

```
namespace :admin, path: "admin/users" do
  resources :teams, except: [:index]
end
```

which gives the following routes:

```
$ rake routes
    admin_teams POST   /admin/users/teams(.:format)          admin/teams#create
 new_admin_team GET    /admin/users/teams/new(.:format)      admin/teams#new
edit_admin_team GET    /admin/users/teams/:id/edit(.:format) admin/teams#edit
     admin_team GET    /admin/users/teams/:id(.:format)      admin/teams#show
                PATCH  /admin/users/teams/:id(.:format)      admin/teams#update
                PUT    /admin/users/teams/:id(.:format)      admin/teams#update
                DELETE /admin/users/teams/:id(.:format)      admin/teams#destroy
```